# How to have zero parindent after visual separators like blank lines or dinkus (but normal parindent for second and subsequent paragraphs)?

Tags: paragraphs, parindent

Here's a minimal LaTeX document that shows (describes) what I'll like to achieve: zero-width `parindent` after a chapter or section title (which happens), a little `parindent` for a subsequent paragraph in the same section (which happens too), but no/zero `parindent` after a visual separator like a dinkus or a blank line. Those separators make a positive `parindent` unnecessary, and not nice to look at.

I tried several things in the commands for `\dinkus` and `\blank`, but with no result. And since the body of the body is supplied as Markdown, I don't want to include `parindent` commands in the document source. I guess (or hope) that the solution can be applied to the `\dinkus` and `\blank` commands, and not to the body.

(To distinguish between my description and the lorem ipsum text, I'm marking the latter as italic. That's all.)

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

% Page style.
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5in}{1.5in}{*} % FIX Fore-edge and spine margins equal (especially for B5 page size).
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*} % FIX Make top and bottom margin larger (especially for B5 page size).
\checkandfixthelayout

% Chapter style.
\chapterstyle{section}

% Create command to insert dinkus on request: * * *.
\newcommand{\dinkus}{
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
  \begin{center}
  {{*\hspace{0.5em}*\hspace{0.5em}*}} % Dinkus to end section.
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0\baselineskip}

  %Insert some `parindent` magic here?
}

% Create command to insert blank line on request.
\newcommand{\blank}{
  \vspace{2.0\baselineskip}

  %Insert similar `parindent` magic here?
}

% Paragraph indenting.
% For stories, make skip less.
\setlength{\parskip}{0\baselineskip}
% For stories, theres no parskip, so a parindent is appropriate.
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

% Begin of document.
\begin{document}

\chapter{Pay attention to parindents}

This paragraph has zero parindent because it is the
first after a chapter title.
\emph{\lipsum[1][1-3]}

This section has a parindent of 1em, as is common for
novels: no or limited parskip but a parindent to show
a new paragraph started.
\emph{\lipsum[1][1-3]}

\section{Wish: no parindents after a dinkus}

This paragraph does not have parindent since it is the
first after a section title. Fine.
\emph{\lipsum[2][1-3]}

\dinkus

But then, after a dinkus separator, Id like to see no
parindent because the new paragraph start does not need 
to be visually separated; it started after a clear separator.
\emph{\lipsum[3][1-3]}

That this paragraph has a parindent is okay, to show that
a new paragrpah started.
\emph{\lipsum[3][1-3]}

\section{And: no parindents after a blank line}

Again, this paragraph has a zero parindent. Great.
\emph{\lipsum[4][1-3]}

This paragraph has a 1em parindent, to visually separate
it from the previous one. Nice.
\emph{\lipsum[5][1-3]}

\blank

But then, after a blank line, again no parindent is necessary.
\emph{\lipsum[6][1-3]}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the same mechanism as `\chapter` and `\section`, that is, `\@afterheading`.

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page style.
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.5in}{1.5in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Chapter style.
\chapterstyle{section}

\makeatletter
% Create command to insert dinkus on request: * * *.
\newcommand{\dinkus}{% <--- IMPORTANT
  \par\nopagebreak\nointerlineskip
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\makebox[\columnwidth]{$*$\enspace$*$\enspace$*$}% Dinkus to end section.
  \par\nointerlineskip\vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading % <---
}

% Create command to insert blank line on request.
\newcommand{\blank}{% <--- IMPORTANT
  \vspace{2.0\baselineskip}%
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading % <---
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Pay attention to parindents}

This paragraph has zero parindent because it is the
first after a chapter title.
\emph{\lipsum[1][1-3]}

This section has a parindent of 1em, as is common for
novels: no or limited parskip but a parindent to show
a new paragraph started.
\emph{\lipsum[1][1-3]}

\section{Wish: no parindents after a dinkus}

This paragraph does not have parindent since it is the
first after a section title. Fine.
\emph{\lipsum[2][1-3]}

\dinkus

But then, after a dinkus separator, Id like to see no
parindent because the new paragraph start does not need 
to be visually separated; it started after a clear separator.
\emph{\lipsum[3][1-3]}

That this paragraph has a parindent is okay, to show that
a new paragrpah started.
\emph{\lipsum[3][1-3]}

\section{And: no parindents after a blank line}

Again, this paragraph has a zero parindent. Great.
\emph{\lipsum[4][1-3]}

This paragraph has a 1em parindent, to visually separate
it from the previous one. Nice.
\emph{\lipsum[5][1-3]}

\blank

But then, after a blank line, again no parindent is necessary.
\emph{\lipsum[6][1-3]}

\end{document}
```

I made some fixes to the definition of `\dinkus` and `\blank`. In the first case I used the math asterisk, which is centered on its line and also `\nointerlineskip` in order to better control the spacing above and below. Also `\nopagebreak` is important or you could have the `\dinkus` at the start of a new page (would you like it?).

Don't load `parskip` with `memoir`: the class has its own methods for emulating it.

[image]

Comment: Is the internal bool `@afterindent` always false? This boolean triggers the `\lastbox` to remove the indentation box.  IMHO it is possible that the boolean is set to true if some of the sectioning commands will be defined in a way that the first paragraph can be indented.  Therefore it is needed to set `\@afterindentfalse` before `\@afterheading`.

Comment: @BerndRaichle Right.

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the quick answer. (I guess you don't need it for your stellar reputation, but I accepted the answer :-))

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX already has a similar mechanism for sectioning commands.  These can be defined in such a way that the following paragraph starts with no indentation (see internal command `\@startsection`, if its `afterskip` argument value is negative the following paragraph starts without indentation).

Internally the macro `\@afterheading` is used in conjunction with a boolean `@afterindent` which needs to be set to false to suppress the indentation.

Add the following (it uses internal commands, thus either move everything into a .sty file or surround it with make at letter/other commands):

```
\newcommand{\suppressfollowingindent}{%
  \par  %\nobreak  % uncomment \nobreak to avoid a page break
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading
}
```

and add this new command where your "parindent magic" is.

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation on the internal logic behind.